# Citrix and hidpi scaling

Tags: scaling

I have posted similar questions about Hidpi scaling in past, and despite the best efforts here; nothing worked, and therefore, elementary OS is kept as a interest.

when i connect to Epic Citrix Server; it doesn't scale.  Unfortunately, elemantary OS only scales via integer so 200%(which is a separate problem as it can't do 150%).   But when I connect, i can't do the 200% scaling.  on a 5K ultrawide monitor, 100% scaling is not usable.  When I do the same with Windows 10 (desktop), MacOS (laptop) both of which scale perfectly (both integer and fractionally).  This always result in me using elementary OS as a interesting side project than actually a day to day OS.

This is part of the reason why I'm not a big fan of fractionated, tiny OSes, where only a few people are working on the project.  Some basic things, or basic software used daily is often not available or has reduced functionality.  Some post from Mr. Fiore or Bleade suggest that they have no plans to A.  include fractional scaling, or B. fix scaling in general.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is something I know very very well :)

The problem lies more in the Citrix Workspace (Former receiver) client rather than in eOS per se. I've tried manually scalling the GTK components out of it but since it was coded with a now-deprecated  library, it won't work as it might with other apps.

Your only choice is to use full resolution (which will require the server-side or destination VDI support) and scale it within the Windows DPI scaling method). But if you use a 5K resolution monitor, chances are that the server policies are defaulting at a maximum graphic memory that won't allow you to go past than 4k Resolution at 32bit color (about 32MBytes of graphic memory per session) and even though some might support 64MB per session, that's normally for dual-4k monitors.

You'll 100% need Citrix Admin-side support to accomplish this, but as of **today**, the Citrix Client won't scale on your eOS sadly.

-Aldo Zampatti

Comment: Thank you for responding.  the wait continues I guess.  In light of everything going on right now; I don't think the Citrix admins are going to be trying to add support for one person on a niche OS at this  time.